# ignoring data using ttp module in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing, text

I am going to explain the problem I faced with the following sample. I am able to parse the following data with the following config. When I used the `{{ignore}}` command, it helps me to get the line as the line matches the correct template, and ignore the data that I don't want to have.

```
from ttp import ttp
import json

data_to_parse = """
1.peace in the world
2.peace in the world world 
3.peace in the world world world 
"""
```

To parse this data I can use the following template.

```
ttp_template = """
<group name="Quote">
{{peace}} in the {{world}}
</group>
<group name="Quote">
{{peace}} in the {{world}} {{ignore}}
</group>
<group name="Quote">
{{peace}} in the {{world}} {{ignore}} {{ignore}}
</group>
"""
```

With the following config, I can have the parsed data as I wish:

```
def parser(data_to_parse):

    parser = ttp(data=data_to_parse, template=ttp_template)
    parser.parse()

    # print result in JSON format
    results = parser.result(format='json')[0]
    #print(results)

    #converting str to json. 
    result = json.loads(results)

    print(result)

parser(data_to_parse)
```

See the output I have:

[image]

**The problem is that** I can not guess how many "world" at the of the each line, and I don't want to keep writing {{ignore}} commands to get the required line and avoid the word that I don't want to have. For example, if I add the following line in my data, it will not be catched with the template I shared above, I will need to add one more {{ignore}} to capture following data.

```
4.peace in the world world world world
```

What I have understood that the reason for this the ttp seperates the words from each space. For example, incase I have `_` instead of 'space' as following `3.peace in the world_world_world` I can get the data with a simple line in my template. However, in my data, I have lines with spaces that I need to be aware of and capture these lines as well.

So the question is that is there any way to facilitate this process? As you see that I have a workaround, however I need to find out a simple way to resolve the issue. Highly appreciate for any advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to resolve this. `{{ name | PHRASE }}` or `{{ name | ORPHRASE }}` can be used for this purpose.

```
{{ name | PHRASE }}
```

This pattern matches any phrase - collection of words separated by single space character, such as “word1 word2 word3”.

```
{{ name | ORPHRASE }}
```

In many cases data that needs to be extracted can be either a single word or a phrase, the most prominent example - various descriptions, such as interface descriptions, BGP peers descriptions etc. ORPHRASE allows to match and extract such a data.

Answer (score 0):

PHRASE matches words separated by a single space.

If needed, you can use a regex pattern in the ignore statetement, so you can match all characters and ignore them.

`{{ ignore('.*') }}` - ignores everything (any characters "." repeating 0 or more time "*") until the end of the line.

so in your case, you could also have used `{{ peace }} in the {{ world }}{{ ignore('.*') }}` Note the missing space between world and ignore, this helps with matching the first entry as well

```
Python 3.11.2 (main, Jun  6 2023, 07:39:01) [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-18)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ttp import ttp
>>> import json
>>> data_to_parse = """
... 1.peace in the world
... 2.peace in the world world
... 3.peace in the world world world
... """
>>> ttp_template = """
... <group name="Quote">
... {{ peace }} in the {{ world }}{{ ignore('.*') }}
... </group>
... """
>>> parser = ttp(data=data_to_parse, template=ttp_template)
>>> parser.parse()
>>> results = parser.result(format='json')[0]
>>> result = json.loads(results)
>>> result
[{'Quote': [{'peace': '1.peace', 'world': 'world'}, {'peace': '2.peace', 'world': 'world'}, {'peace': '3.peace', 'world': 'world'}]}]
>>> exit()
```